# FileChangedReloadingStrategy not reflecting changes made in application.properties file without restarting server

Tags: java, spring, jboss

I am using Spring MVC with jboss server 7, i googled and found below code

```
Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("application.properties");
    final PropertiesConfiguration property = new PropertiesConfiguration(resource.getURL());
    //set the reloading strategy
    property.setReloadingStrategy(new FileChangedReloadingStrategy());
```

My requirement is that whenever i make any changes in **application.properties file it has to get reflected in application without restarting server**. i am using jboss 7 server. In war file i have application.properties file inside class folder, **if i make any changes in that and on just refreshing, changes has to get reflect in my app**.

I googled about this and found above code, but it is not working on changes made and refresh immediatly. **Current code only reflects on restarting server.**

**Is this the right one to use or what will be the suggestion to my requirement?**
Please help on this.